# R thinks it is five hours ahead

Tags: r, timezone, rstudio

I have a function that uses file.info to get the creation time of some archives. However, since I changed to my Mac it gives me five hours ahead.
The same happens when I use `Sys.time()` it shows me the correct date but five hours ahead.

```
> Sys.time() 
[1] "2020-04-07 18:52:38 GMT"
```

I think it is related to my Time Zone GMT-5:00. How can I make both functions give me the right answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change globally the parameter, for instance,

```r
Sys.setenv(TZ = "Europe/Paris")
```

If you just want to change the output of your expression. In base R you can do

```r
as.POSIXct(format(Sys.time()),tz="Europe/Paris")
```

You can also use `lubridate::with_tz`

```r
lubridate::with_tz(Sys.time(), "Europe/Paris")
```

You can of course use your own timezone, not forced to use French timezone ;)